# Passing a dir as argument and show its last modified date

Tags: c, date, directory, dir, stat

OK, so I was thinking of a program that displays my folder's or file's last modified time; I succeeded doing that, but I passed only the path as argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int count , char *args[]){
    char buffer[50];
    struct stat attr;
    if(count < 2){
        printf("No parameters passed");
    }
    else{
        strcpy(buffer,args[1]);
        stat(buffer,&attr);
        printf("Last modiffied date time : % s" , ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which works! But I was wondering if I could do that using a DIR instead a char path.
Something like:

```
.........
DIR *mydir;
struct dirent *dir;
dir = opendir(args[1]);
```

NOTES: However I found out that the stat function that I used earlier (path as argument) has these parameters:

```
int stat(const char*restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

Which took me to this question:

How can I really show the stat of the folder (in my case last modified date), if I can't use this function?

**EDIT**

My try so far using dirent:

```
..........
DIR *mydir;
struct stat attr;
mydir = opendir(args[1]);
stat(mydir,&attr);
printf("last modified is... %s" , ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
return 0;
```

I get this warning:

> ```
> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stat’ from incompatible pointer type
> /usr/include/sys/stat.h:211: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct DIR *’
> ```

Comment: you can stat a directory

Comment: Not really understanding what your problem is. Just pass `args[1]` as the first parameter to `stat`. Or please clarify your question if that isn't what you need.

Comment: @AlanAu Thank you I've tried but i get a warning and my modified date doesn't show correctly ; I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You can't use a `DIR` with `stat`.

What's wrong with passing the name of the directory?

Comment: Nothing wrong , I was just wondering If I could use another method .. well that's what I wanted to know . Thank you.

Comment: @Lazai Well, there's `fstat`, which takes a file descriptor, but I don't know of a way to get a file descriptor from `DIR *` either.

Comment: Yeah well , at first I was thinking getting the folder's inode ... but don't know how this could help me.